# Output numbers in reverse (C++) w/ vectors

Tags: c++, vector, reverse

I'm stuck for the first time on a lab for this class.  Please help!

The prompt is:
*Write a program that reads a list of integers, and outputs those integers in reverse. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. For coding simplicity, follow each output integer by a comma, including the last one.

Ex: If the input is:

5 2 4 6 8 10

the output is:

10,8,6,4,2,*

2 questions: (1) Why does the vector not take user input unless the const int is included? (2) Why does the code not work in general?  It seems to properly output, but with an error, and does not include the end line?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   
using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int MAX_ELEMENTS = 20;
   vector<int> userInts(MAX_ELEMENTS);
   unsigned int i;
   int numInts;
   
   cin >> numInts;
   
   for (i = 0; i < numInts; ++i) {
      cin >> userInts.at(i);
   }
   
   for (i = (numInts - 1); i >= 0; --i) {
      cout << userInts.at(i) << ",";
   }

   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: See `std::vector::push_back`.

Comment: For `unsigned int i`, condition `i >= 0` is always true. Think how this impacts your program.

Comment: And once you have the number in the `vector` correctly, print them out with the help of [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin). See the example at the bottom of the linked documentation page to see reverse iterators in action.

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to be using reverse iterators yet as it hasn't been covered in the material.  This chapter involved vectors, resizing, push_back, swapping, a bit on arrays, etc...

Comment: instead of `for (i = (numInts - 1); i >= 0; --i) { cout << userInts.at(i) << ","; }` you could `for (i = numInts; i > 0; --i) { cout << userInts.at(i-1) << ","; }`

Comment: Bummer about the reverse iterators, but at least you know they are an option for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to specify the size because you are not using the `vector`'s `push_back` functionality. Since you are only using `at`, you must specify the size ahead of time. Now, there's a few ways to do this.

Example 1:

```
cin >> numInts;
vector<int> userInts(numInts); // set the size AFTER the user specifies it
   
for (i = 0; i < numInts; ++i) {
   cin >> userInts.at(i);
}
```

Alternatively, using `push_back` you can do:

```
vector<int> userInts; // set the size AFTER the user specifies it
   
for (i = 0; i < numInts; ++i) {
   int t;
   cin >> t;
   userInts.push_back(t);
}
```

As for looping backwards, `i >= 0` will always be true for unsigned numbers. Instead, you can use iterators.

```
for ( auto itr = userInts.rbegin(); itr != userInts.rend(); ++itr ) {
    cout << *itr;
}
```

If you *need* to use indexes for the reverse loop, you can do:

```
for ( i = numInts - 1; i != ~0; --i ) { // ~0 means "not 0", and is the maximum value, I believe this requires c++17 or 20 though
    cout << userInts.at(i);
}
```

Comment: Wow you guys rock.  Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

with `unsigned int i;` the condition `i >= 0` is always true. Eventually you will access an out-of-range element, which will throw `std::out_of_range`.

Comment: Thank you.  I assume there must be a different strategy to this altogether since I believe the material said we must use unsigned int for the loop index.  Sorry, I'm very new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question

```
  std::vector userInts;
```

create a vector with no entries

```
 userInts.at(i)
```

tries to access the (non existnat) ith entry.

You have 2 choices

- create vector with a lot of empty etries
- ask the vector to dynamically grow

The first one is what you did

```
 const int MAX_ELEMENTS = 20;
 vector<int> userInts(MAX_ELEMENTS);
```

Or you can do

```
 userInts.push_back(x);
```

this will make sure there is enough space in the vector and add the new element to the end.

Comment: This makes so much sense, thank you!  The template included just "vector<int> userInts" and I added the "(MAX_ELEMENTS)" since it wasn't working without it.  Now I see why!